# How to completely remove files left by appimage and appimage launcher? Uninstalling / Removing did not work. Residue left

Tags: linux, debian, application, appimage

I removed the AppImage launcher using `apt uninstall appimagelauncher` and deleted the appimage files from `~/Applications` as well but it didn't remove the two apps I had imstalled using appimage i.e. Visual studio code and OnlyOffice. I can still see their menu entry when I search for them.

[image: onlyoffice]

[image: visual studio's application launher]

Even when I do a catfish search I see leftovers like these. I think It's because the appimage launcher integrates the images or something IIRC. So is there any way to ensure no residue is left?

[image: my fucing luck]

Some help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

This is how you properly remove applications that have been completely integreaed by appimage launcher-

1. Install [the lite version of appimage launcher](https://github.com/TheAssassin/AppImageLauncher/releases/tag/v2.2.0) and run it
2. Make it executable and run it in terminal with `./Appimage...<command>`
3. Run `./appimage... cli unintegrate ~/Applications/$NAME_OF_PACKAGE`
4. Then finally to remove the appimage launcher itself run `./appimage... remove`

You can see more availabe commands using `./appimage... --help`